# Testing redirection using regex.test() instead of Jasmine expect

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm testing the redirection after the sign-up of an AngularJs app.
After clicking the registration button i call a function to check if the url matches with `targetRegex`.
The first code block use Jasmine `expect` but the i get the error: `timeout: timed out after 30000 msec waiting for spec to complete`

```
   return browser.wait(function() {
     return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
       return expect(url).toContain(targetRegex);
     });
   });
```

Meanwhile the following code seems working well:

```
  return browser.wait(function() {
    return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
      return targetRegex.test(url); // look for a match of the regex /profile/ in the 'url'
    });
  });
```

Is anybody able to explain me why please?

Comment: What is the actual URL when the first one fails?

Comment: from `console.log(url)` is `http://localhost/profile/200490`

Answer (score 0):

From the [Jasmine docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html): *The 'toContain' matcher is for finding an item in an Array*.

For matching via a regular expression, I think you want to use `toMatch` instead, as in `expect(url).toMatch(targetRegex);`.

However, I'm not sure if you want to use that `toMatch` method after `return`. It doesn't return a simple boolean result. If you look at the [source code for that method](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/matchers/toMatch.js), you'll see that it returns an object with a `compare` method. Judging from the source code for other methods in the *matchers* subdirectory, apparently that's a standard pattern used internally by the Jasmine library.

So, bottom line, you might be better off sticking with the `return targetRegex.test(url);` approach instead, since that returns a boolean.

Comment: ok thx i got it! Anyway, is it good using plain Js in tests? Shouldn't i use Jasmine's expectations when "i'm checking a condition"?